# How to limit the actions of a user in django CBV

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I've got a theoretical question. For example I've got 2 blogs of 2 users. When I'm logged in as a first user I can see posts of the second user, but not only see but also update them and delete them. The same holds true to the second user which can delete and update the posts of the first user. What should i do in django class base view so that the first user can only edit and delete his own posts but not the posts of other users. I've come across `request.user == post.user` check in function based view. But what are the solutions for class based views. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach is to override the `get_queryset` method and filter it using `self.request.user`.

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyView, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```